# Chess board corners probability problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have a chess board (8*8) and we distribute 8 different chess pieces (4 different white pieces and 4 different black pieces) what is the probability of having only black on the corners of the board.

So I thought the probability space would be ${64 \choose 8}$ since we have 64 squares and we need to distribute 8 pieces to it.
and for the number of combinations to chose 4 black for the 4 corners I seem to be lost , I tried $4!$*${4 \choose 1}$*$4$ since we have 4! ways to sort the black ones and we need to pick one out of 4 for each corner ${4 \choose 1}$ and multiply by 4 for the white ones

The final answer should be $1.574*10^{-6}$ according to the book but I am not even close to this..

Appreciate any help and tips! thank you

Comment: Hint: Ignore the white pieces and place the black pieces.  What is the probability that they all go in corners?

Comment: Are you allowed to put more than one piece in a square?

Comment: @awkward thank you for the hint but I seem to be doing it wrong , now my space should be ${64 \choose 4}$ (?) and the combinations is $4*4!$? this seems wrong to me I feel like I am missing a lot of things here. thanks again

Comment: @RossMillikan they did not mention that so I am guessing that only 1 piece in a square

Comment: You are close.  Out of the $\binom{64}{4}$ subsets of size $4$, how many of those subsets include all four corner squares?

Comment: @RossMillikan took me a while to figure out what you guys suggested thank you all for the awesome tips and hints finally got it right :) in 2 ways one involving the white $1*4!*$ ${60 \choose 4}$ $*4!$ and divide by ${64 \choose 8}$ $*8!$ and the other way which is only considering the black ones would be $1$ divide by ${60 \choose 4}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place the black pieces in order.  What is the chance the first goes into a corner?  Now that a corner is occupied, what is the chance that the second goes into a corner?  Keep going.

Comment: @Adamrk A somewhat rare probability problem.  Your instinct to compute the probability as $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}$$ where you first enumerate $D$ and then enumerate $N$ is a good instinct.  It just so happens that the alternative approach, re this answer allows elegance.